# Get default first children routing angularjs

Tags: angularjs

After login page I go to home page and I want to call directly the default children in home page

this config in app.js

```
 .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        component: 'login'
      })
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        component: 'home'
      })
      .state('home.listTemplates', {
        url: '/listTemplates',
        component: 'listTemplates'
      });
  })
```

I want that d listTemplates will be opened directly when I open home page

it works but just when I complete the url manually

this is my home conttroller

```
class HomeController {
  constructor($state) {
    this.name = 'home';
    console.log('home controller');

  }
}


HomeController.$inject = ['$state'];
export default HomeController;
```

home.component

```
import template from './home.html'
import controller from './home.controller';
let HomeComponent = {
  restrict : 'E',
  template,
  controller
};
export default HomeComponent;
```

home.js

```
import HomeComponent from './home.component';
import ListTemplatesComponent from 'listTemplates/listTemplates.component';
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular.module('home',[
  uiRouter
])
  .config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)=> {
    "ngInject";

  })
.component('home',HomeComponent)
.component('listTemplates',ListTemplatesComponent);
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

for

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', {redirectTo: '/listTemplates'}).otherwise('/');
```